# Configuring security for WFS layer

Tags: geoserver, wfs, security

We are using GeoServer 2.8, PostgreSQL 9.6 & QGIS 2.16 on our side. We have certain WFS layers.
As per [documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/service.html) disabled Anonymous WFS access and looking more settings for Web part.

However in QGIS by adding our GeoServer IP details using URL like "http://123.456.789.25/geoserver/wfs?" can able to add WFS service connection and able to download data in shapefile format, but not able to 'edit data' that's good part.

How to disable 'save as to shapefile' option for WFS service? Is there anything more need to configure on GeoServer?

Please check following screenshot
[image]

Checking on [Geo-server security links](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/index.html) for reference

Answer (score 3):

You can't disable downloading data with a WFS service, that's what a WFS service does.  In QGIS you are downloading the data as GML then saving as shapefile, so there's nothing to configure in GeoServer.